# change event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code on change event handler,

```
<style>
    p {
      margin: 20px 0 0;
    }
    b {
      color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<body>

    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" xyz="abc">
    <label for="check1">Check me</label>
    <p></p>

    <script>
    $( "input" )
        .change(function() {
        var $input = $( this );
        $( "p" ).html( ".attr( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.attr("checked") + "</b><br>" +
                            ".attr( 'xyz' ): <b>" + $input.attr("xyz") + "</b><br>"  +
            ".prop( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.prop("checked") + "</b><br>" +
            ".is( ':checked' ): <b>" + $input.is( ":checked" ) + "</b>" );
        })
        .change();
    </script>

</body>
```

---

Observation is, `change` event handler function gets immediately executed on loading of script.

But, call expression is evaluated from left to right. So, `.change()` can be called only after `$('input').change(handler)` is executed successfully.

So, How `.change()` call expression is invoked, without executing `$('input').change(handler)`?

Comment: he called change manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the question is here. It does exactly what you stated. It sets an `change` event handler, and then immediately calls it. There could be any number of reasons to do this, and without context it's impossible to tell.

The `.change()` at the end does indeed simply call emulate the event and call the handler.

jQuery calls tend to return their associated object so that method chaining can be used. The code above is equivalent to the following:

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    $( "p" ).html( ".attr( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.attr("checked") + "</b><br>" +
                        ".attr( 'xyz' ): <b>" + $input.attr("xyz") + "</b><br>"  +
        ".prop( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.prop("checked") + "</b><br>" +
        ".is( ':checked' ): <b>" + $input.is( ":checked" ) + "</b>" );
    });

$("input").change();
```

Because it is evaluated in left to right order as you stated, and the `.change(function(). . . )` call returns the jQuery collection fetched via `$("input")`, method chaining is possible.

You can do this with basically any jQuery object

```
$("p").css({color:"red"}).text("error").show()
```

is a similar bit of code that utilizes jQuery's method chaining.

Comment: So, Are you saying that `$( "input" ).change(handler)` is just setting the change event handler to the jQuery object but not invoking the handler? Later when you invoke `.change()`, the handler gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $("p").html(".attr( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.attr("checked") + "</b><br>" +
      ".attr( 'xyz' ): <b>" + $input.attr("xyz") + "</b><br>" +
      ".prop( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.prop("checked") + "</b><br>" +
      ".is( ':checked' ): <b>" + $input.is(":checked") + "</b>");
  });
})
```

You should use `$(document).ready( function() {...} )`. This way all the code inside the function is only executed after the document is ready (has loaded)